# dart:html is placed inside the file but Error is not found?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I have a project using JSON APIs was working fine suddenly error occurs while i was debugging my application and want to modify but when i restarted the app it suddenly shows the following error. The required `import 'dart:html';` is already in that file. but don't know why this happens. I tried to `import dart.io` but same issue. i tried to to restart and invilidate caches but the problem exist.
***Error:***

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X652 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: E:\Flutter Projects\criclite\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d908c0f5b30e137aa06d363a041f44ee\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: E:\Flutter Projects\criclite\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d908c0f5b30e137aa06d363a041f44ee\kernel_snapshot.d
lib/ui/News.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
```

**Note:** project was working fine this issue suddenly comes out without any changes made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove import  `dart:html`
then flutter clean
and run will resolve issue.

Comment: Issue Resolved Thanks

Comment: @QasimAli : Please mark this answer as accepted. thank you.